# Using Open Source Ruby Motion

Tags: ruby, git

It would be really great if you could help me with this.

I wish to work on the open source version of Ruby Motion. I gave the following commands to get the version from Git

```
$ git clone https://github.com/HipByte/RubyMotion.git
$ cd RubyMotion
$ git submodule update --init
```

Till this Command I am able to proceed without hindrance.
When I give the following Command I get something Like "Library/RubyMotion/lib" is not found.

```
$ rake install
```

But the system has got the RubyMotion/lib file in another location after the first steps, but even if I create a folder named Library and do the steps to replace the lib I get the same error.

Comment: Try to create the missing folder and try again

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Could you please let me know if the folder has to be in any location or if that can be in the Admin folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't RubyMotion, it's just the open source parts. You will still need a RubyMotion license.

Comment: Thank you so Much....Should we buy the License for sure to work on Ruby Motion or would they have a free License for some trial period

Comment: You can buy a license and if you're not happy with it in the first 30 days you can get a refund :)

Answer (score 0):

Their Website "rubymotion.com" states (click on buy or use link below)

http://sites.fastspring.com/hipbyte/product/rubymotion

"
Want to give RubyMotion a try? Go ahead, we offer a 30 days money back guarantee. 
"

Answer (score 0):

Now you can get a free RubyMotion version for Android and iOS projects.

Just fill this form:

http://www.rubymotion.com/download/starter/